Determination of signal amplitude distribution
For context, this figure from the reference Figure 1 of paper [1] shows, producing a signal amplitude probability generation.

When the distance $\Delta x$ is infinitely small, the probability
density of signal amplitude is as follows: $$ p(x)=\lim _{\Delta x
\rightarrow 0} \frac{P[x<x(t) \leq x+\Delta x]}{\Delta x}=\lim
_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\Delta x}\left[\lim _{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{T_x}{T}\right] . $$
For a sampling time sequence $x(n)$, we have:
$$ p(x)=\lim _{\substack{\Delta x \rightarrow 0 \\ N \rightarrow
\infty}} \frac{1}{N \Delta x} n_x $$


I am searching for an analytical expression to estimate the distribution of amplitudes of a Gaussian function, i.e., to determine how its amplitude values are distributed. For example, for a sine wave, the amplitude distribution resembles a U-shape, which is well-documented in textbooks and online resources.
This query is a parallel question Probability distribution for a noisy sine wave, but it concerns a Gaussian function rather than a sinusoidal one. A reference would also be helpful. However, I am surprised to find little to no references for the amplitude distribution of a Gaussian function.
To clarify, how can we extract the amplitude distribution following the Gaussian function?
$$
a(t) = H \cdot e^{-\frac{(t - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
where:

$H$ is the maximum peak height of the Gaussian,
$\mu$ is the mean or the center,
$\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

For example, let $H = 1$, $\mu = 5$, and $\sigma = 1.0$.
Numerical experiments in MATLAB, such as constructing histograms of the amplitude values of the Gaussian, suggest the amplitude distribution is asymmetric. Below is a numerical estimate of the distribution:
Is there a closed-form analytical expression for the distribution of amplitudes of a Gaussian function?
For the more context, a quote the text from Telecommunication Principles by J. J. O’Reilly (1984), pg 47-49. is reproduced, where the author shows examples of periodic functions.

Amplitude Distribution of Signals

For a deterministic signal such as a cosine wave the time domain
description is a precise characterization of the instantaneous
variation of the amplitude of the signal; it indicates the amplitude
of the signal for each value of the time variable $t$. For a randomly
varying signal such as a speech waveform no such precise and complete
description is possible. Nevertheless, it is generally useful (and
often necessary) to have some sort of signal characterization relating
to possible amplitude values. This is provided by the amplitude
distribution which is a measure of the relative frequency of
occurrence of the various instantaneous values of the signal. The
amplitude distribution of a signal $x(t)$ is denoted by $$ p(x)=\lim
 _{\mathrm{d} x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\text { fraction of time spent in } \mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{~d} x} $$ where $\mathrm{d} x$ is an elemental
interval centred on $x$. An illustrative signal waveform and its
corresponding amplitude distribution is shown in Fig. 2.25.
Given the amplitue distribution $p(x)$, the fraction of time the
amplitude of a signal $x(t)$ lies within the interval $\left(x_1,
x_2\right)$ can be calculated as $$
F\left(x_1<x<x_2\right)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} p(x) \mathrm{d} x $$
Note that the fraction of time a signal spends in an interval can
never be negative and that the signal always has some finite
amplitude, hence: $$ \begin{aligned} & p(x) \geq 0 \text { for all } x
\\ & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) \mathrm{d} x=1 \end{aligned} $$
An alternative interpretation of $F\left(x_1<x<x_2\right)$ is that it
measures the probability that a randomly selected sample of the signal
$x(t)$ falls within the interval $\left(x_1, x_2\right)$. This
probability can be obtained by integrating $p(x)$ over the interval
and $p(x)$ is thus usually referred to as a probability density
function.


[1]: H. Li, D. Du, X. You, and Q. He, “Direct calculation method of probability density from sampled vibration signal based on linear interpolation method,” Journal of Vibroengineering, Vol. 19, No. 7, pp. 5086–5103, Nov. 2017, https://doi.org/10.21595/jve.2017.18772

Just to be sure I understand your question correctly: your signal is a deterministic signal, in the shape of a Gaussian "bell" curve, right?

Yes, you are right. It is deterministic. If I create a histogram of a Gaussian, it is also like a asymmetric U, with more values near zero, and a small branch on the right near the maximum amplitude values. I am wondering, how to estimate it mathematically.

As Hilmar wrote, that would be 0 nearly everywhere, even without doing any formula work on this,just thinking about how the function expands into infinity and doesn't take any value exactly for any interval that has a length > 0. So this seems to start with the general question "What is a histogram, and how do I compute it, given a function?", then it is about the Gaussian. The text you cite assumes "given the amplitude distribution", and a slightly "lax" definition of that, without really motivating it. Do you perhaps need to take a step back and ask how to compute the amplitude distribution?

Marcus, see my comment to Hilmar, which mentions the entire purpose of this effort.

This is a somewhat ill-posed question. All the functions in your examples are more or less "stationary", i.e. they have infinite support and what happens at different points in time is more or less the same.
That's not the case for a bell curve. Technically it has infinite support, but its certainly not "stationary". There is bump around $t = \mu$ and it decays very quickly as you move away from the mean.
So the PDF is dependent in the observation window and if you use an infinite window it will very much look like a Dirac delta at 0 since the vast majority of all amplitudes will be exceedingly small.
You could try to derive the PDF of a normal bell curve by starting with something simple and working our way up:
$$f_1(x) = |x|, f_2(x) = -f_1(x)^2, f_3(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{f_2(x)}$$
But we run in the same problem with the first function. The PDF of $f1_(x) = |x|$ depends on the observation window. All positive amplitudes are equally probable but as the observation window goes to infinity the probability goes to 0.

Hilmar, You are right. I think we have to focus on a time interval otherwise instead of infinite time on both ends. As you stated, we will have a near delta function from far away at 0. My eventual goal of this entire exercise was eventually on how to calculate the (information) entropy, which requires a knowledge of probability amplitudes, of a signal that contains a Gaussian peak with some noise within a given time frame.

@ACR wait, but entropy is a property of a random variable, not of a deterministic function, so that's a conflict. The entropy of a deterministic function is 0, since it's deterministic. So, that's not what you want! Can you maybe give us a better view into what connects this to the question of entropy?

What students usually want to answer is "what's the differential entropy of a random variable with Gaussian amplitude distribution?" and then, the amplitude distribution is the Gaussian. You're trying to answer the question "what is the amplitude distribution of a Gaussian function", and that's a completely different thing.

Let me suggest a problem which I am trying to tackle (certainly not as a student!). Suppose you have a noisy signal that contains a Gaussian peak or it can have multiple peaks from a instrument. It is deterministic in the sense, that we have that data and it is reproducible. The objective is to minimize the information entropy = denoising of this signal. Image processing folks use the histograms (of amplitudes etc.) to calculate entropies of images signals etc. This is where I was trying to go.

Ah, so the actual randomness is in the position (and possibly standard deviation) of these peaks? That'd be a classic communications engineering problem, then!

You are 100% right! It stems from Shannon's work of 1940s. And I have contacted a dozen of mathematicians all over the world without much success. It is a difficult problem, not in communications but chemistry rather,  but doable, hopefully one day.

yeah, but your problem as described has nothing to do with the things you're trying to calculate. And the mathematicians might just have been confused by that :) Can you maybe ask a new question (because this one already has an answer) where you describe the bigger picture (i.e., with the Gaussian peak / multiple instrument peaks, and what you measure and how) and ask how to solve that? You are exactly in the right group of engineers and math-heavy people to get an answer to that higher-level problem, and we can always drill down on more specific problems while solving that :)
